# u3d or prc writer library for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, f#, 3d

Is there any .NET library / .NET wrapper library capable of writing/reading u3d or prc file formats, which can then be used in the PDF?

Answer (score 1):

[iText](http://itextpdf.com/itext.php), a PDF creation library is available in Java and .NET. They have a Java example which manipulates u3d format [here](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=299). I guess you can do similar things in .NET.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The example however assumes that you already have `teapot.u3d` which I don´t. So what I basically need, is to programmatically write either u3d or prc.